# How to remove integer(0) from a vector?

Tags: r, function, matrix, vector

I have two large matrices and I want to calculate a similarity score between the two. However, there are some columns in these matrices that contain gaps so what I did was write a function that creates a score matrix (1 for similarity 0 for dissimilarity) then created `gaps` and `nogaps` vectors from the matrix and calculated the score accordingly
The scoring part of the function is seen below

```
  ScoreMat <- align1 == align2

  #find gaps and nogaps
  gaps   <- which(align1 == "-", arr.in=TRUE)
  gaps   <- gaps[,2]
  gaps   <-gaps[!duplicated(gaps) ]
  nogaps <- 1:ncol(align1)
  nogaps <- nogaps[-gaps]

  #split ScoreMat into gaps and nogaps matrices
  ScoreMatgaps     <- ScoreMat[,gaps]
  ScoreMatNogaps   <- ScoreMat[,nogaps]

  #calculate score
  gapScore   <- rowSums(ScoreMatgaps)
  nogapScore <- rowSums(ScoreMatNogaps)
  score      <- cbind(gapScore,nogapScore)
```

The problem starts when I want to score specific column ranges that I am more interested in than the others. So the greater function contains lines on how to score these specific ranges. However, some of these ranges contain gaps, others do not. So for the ranges that have gaps, the function works properly. But with the ranges that do not have gaps, the `gaps` vector returns as `integer(0)` and for some reason, the `nogaps` vector gives that result as well.

My attempt at fixing the issue included using an if statement as follows:

```
  gaps   <- which(align1 == "-", arr.in=TRUE)
  gaps   <- gaps[,2]
  gaps   <- gaps[!duplicated(gaps) ]
  nogaps <- 1:ncol(align1)
  nogaps <- ifelse (length(gaps) == 0, nogaps, nogaps[-gaps])
```

But this leads to `nogaps` to be equal to 1

Why is the if statement giving this result, and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware using the negative indices in the `[` operator. I strongly suggest to avoid using them as much as you can. I won't talk specifically of your problem, since you didn't provide a reproducible example. On the other hand, I guess that the problem comes from the following. Suppose I have a vector and I want to remove the negative values. I can do the following:

```
v<-rnorm(100)
indices<-which(v<0)
v<-v[-indices]
```

The above works fine. Suppose now that there aren't negative values, so you want to keep the entire vector. What happens if you follow the above procedure?

```
v<-1:10
indices<-which(v<0)
v<-v[-indices]
v
#integer(0)
```

We don't have nothing! Remember that `x[-integer(0)]` produces a 0 length vector. The solution? Instead of the elements you want to remove, state the ones you want to keep! Very simple. Like this:

```
#state the opposite condition
indices<-which(v>=0)
v<-v[indices]
```

This will work in any instance. My guess is that your problem comes from `nogaps[-gaps]` and similar lines.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I don't know why I didn't think of it sooner!

Comment: after scratching my head for a hours, I came to the conclusion that your suggestion does not work. This is because all columns in my matrices has a few rows that have no gaps (in other words, the columns with gaps have both gaps and data) so finding the columns with no gaps at all is not possible. I will update my question with my fix attempt (which I am having an issue with)

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example and your desired output, as your problem  is unclear. However, in your edit you should use `if ... else` and not `ifelse` (which is a vectorized version and is not needed). Try `nogaps <- if (length(gaps) == 0) nogaps else nogaps[-gaps]`

Comment: Thank you nicola for your help, 'if... else' worked perfectly for what I needed to do. Thanks again